# Resetting redux states on url change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, connected-react-router

I have a project that redux working on. But when I click on a `<Link>` component or click on to the "previous page" button on chrome, redux keeps the states I changed before. I tried the `LOCATION_CHANGE` action from `connected-react-router` and use it in reducer but it does not seem to work.

reducer:

```
import {LOCATION_CHANGE} from "connected-react-router"
function reducer(state=defaultState,action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOCATION_CHANGE:
            console.log("changed")
            return defaultState
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: have you some code to show ?

Comment: I don't have that much code to show. Just react, firebase, and a bit of redux stuff dispatching other things.

Comment: I made an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this :

```
class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      dispatch({ type: LOCATION_CHANGE });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <App/>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` not but `componentWillUnmount` is working for links and next page, `componentDidMount` for back page. Thanks for idea

Comment: ok sorry I couldn't try it for you, you're welcome